# Not able to download all the reactjs packages. Only getting node_modules, package-lock.json and package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
(base) Shwetas-MacBook-Pro:my-app shwetabhatt$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shwetabhatt/.npm/_logs/2020-10-20T19_01_44_088Z-debug.log
(base) Shwetas-MacBook-Pro:my-app shwetabhatt$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shwetabhatt/.npm/_logs/2020-10-20T19_02_23_518Z-debug.log
(base) Shwetas-MacBook-Pro:my-app shwetabhatt$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shwetabhatt/.npm/_logs/2020-10-20T19_04_30_514Z-debug.log
```

Getting this on the terminal after "npm start"
It downloads only node_modules, package-lock.json and package.json and not the rest.

Upon opening the directory in the above code, getting this:

```
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
```

Comment: what cmd did you use to set up the project? share your package.json

Comment: After installing and checking the versions of npm and node,  used "npx create-react-app my-app" to create the app. Got "A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported." on terminal after that

Answer (score 0):

To download all the packages you firstly need to run this in the project directory:

`npm install`

After that you can check `package.json` file and add what the script "start" will do (this is an example how `package.json` can look like and it should be fairly similar to yours except for the dependenices):

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/blabla/test.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/blabla/test.git/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.5",
    "npm": ">=5.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

As you can see in the `script` I have defined what the "start" command will perform.

After that you should be able to run `npm run start`.

I sent a `package.json` from a nodeJS project. Can you send how your `package.json` looks like?

If there is any question don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: "{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  }
}" That's how my package.json looks like.
"A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app." getting this on the terminal after "create-react..."
Not getting any results even after "npm install"

Comment: Could your send a screenshot of how your project-directory looks like?